# What presentation-creator app can do zoom-ins and zoom-outs well?

Tags: animation, microsoft-powerpoint

I am interested in creating a presentation that is based on a shrunken view of a large system flow.  Each area of the flow, in turn, I'd like to zoom in on, explain in detail, then zoom out back to the overall image (wash, rinse, repeat).

So my question is bifurcated:

1. I don't think Microsoft PPT or open-source analogs can do this well, but if they
   can, I'd sure love to know: what's the technique?
2. Or, if I am right and
       they aren't the tool for this job, what other tools are out there
       that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a lot of presentations created using [Prezi](http://prezi.com/) that have this sort of functionality.

> Prezi is a virtual whiteboard that transforms presentations from monologues into conversations: enabling people to see, understand, and remember ideas.
>
> To understand complexity, one must zoom out to see the big picture and in to see the details. Prezi’s 3-dimensional canvas is a virtual space where you can delve deeper and pan wider to broaden the conversation.

You can check out the [examples](http://prezi.com/explore/popular/) on their site to see what I mean. One in particular that incorporates this sort of "zooming in and out" is "[My E-Textbook](http://prezi.com/43fyg5a3ciyg/my-e-textbook/)".

[image: Presentation start]

[image: Zoomed in slide]

Comment: +1 for prezi. I use it; it works well, just do not overdo the flying and zooming too much.